# topological space problem

Tags: general-topology

X={a,b,c}, $f:\mathbb{R} \to X$ $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      a & x< 0 \\
      b &  x=0 \\
      c &  x>0 
   \end{cases}$$
$\tau_{s}$ standart topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is given.Find yout coaser topology that makes f continuous over X let show this topology $V_{f}$ and investigate if the $(X,V_{f})$ topologic space is $T_{0}$ and $T_{1}$

Comment: What you try to do?

Comment: How can we find the stronger Vf

Answer (score 2):

Edit: can you clarify what you mean by thinnest?

I can't add comments yet so I'll post it here: this question as it is stated is trivial since you can just choose the trivial topology on $X$.

Indeed, let $V_f=\{X,\emptyset\}$. Notice that any function $g:Y \rightarrow X$ (here $Y$ is any topological space) is continuous, since we only need to check that $g^{-1}(X)=Y$ and $\emptyset$ are open. They are by definition of topology.

Notice that in this case $(X,V_f)$ is not $T_0$, since for any two distinct points $x,y\in X$ the only open set containing them is the whole space. In particular it's not $T_1$ either.

Comment: But maybe isn't the thinnest topology that makes $f$ continuous.

Comment: I understand thin as having few open sets, am I wrong? I'm only used to coarser/finer for comparing topologies

Comment: Oh you a right, I was confused with the discrete topology :P.

Comment: weaker or smaller

Comment: Then just choose the trivial topology which is not T0

Comment: how can I define $V_{f}$ topolgy

Comment: I have edited my reply